# Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \ln(3^\frac{n}{1}+3^\frac{n}{2}+\cdots+3^\frac{n}{n})$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot\ln(3^\frac{n}{1}+3^\frac{n}{2}+\cdots+3^\frac{n}{n})$$
I tried to apply the squeeze theorem, but I can't manage to solve it.

Comment: Try moving $\frac1n$ inside the $\ln$ and then use AM-GM

Comment: Hint: upper bounds for $n/1, n/2, n/3, \ldots, n/n$ are $n, n-1, n-2, \ldots, 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The squeeze theorem is a good idea.  $$
\ln(3^n)\leq  \ln(3^\frac{n}{1}+3^\frac{n}{2}+\cdots+3^\frac{n}{n}) \leq \ln(n\cdot3^n)
$$

Comment: Thank you! The result is $\ln 3$